# Proper way to track emails

Tags: email, analytics, tracking

I currently use Thunderbird to send out my email campaigns. Since I do not have resources to pay for an email application with tracking built in, I was wondering if there are recommended ways to track opens in emails that I code myself?

Comment: You could try using [shiftmail.io](https://shiftmail.io)'s services (they're free)

Answer (score 0):

A tracking pixel is often used to do this. It's just an image 1px by 1px that you include in the email. Then you look through your server log to see how many times that image was downloaded. The issue with this solution is that many people have their emails set to not download images automatically and they have to accept them first (which not everyone does) so it may not be 100% accurate.

Comment: This is the only way to track opens outside of clicking a link.

Comment: @John - Yea, it appears this is the [technique Mailchimp uses](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/about-open-tracking) as well.  I can't imagine it's very accurate, I very rarely display images in my emails.

Comment: @MikeChristensen All email clients that track opens use this technique. It's definately not perfect, but it is the only non-click method to do it. It is also lopsided as mac clients emails open with images on by default, so the open stats sway towards mac users. Unfortunately unless you are counting only clicks, there is no way to accurately compare data.

Comment: Understood that the 1x1 pixel method is all that we have besides clicking a link (Google Analytics or another method) but I am just looking to see if there is a program that can handle the tracking for me and all I need is to embed some code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many email service providers that offer free plans. [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/pricing/) for example lets you send 12,000 emails per month for up to 2000 subscribers without paying a dime. Only catch is that you have to include their logo at the bottom of your email.

Research email service providers and you'll find most of them have a free option available. Here is a [big list of ESP's](http://email-marketing-services.findthebest.com/) to get you started.

Another free option is [PHPList](http://www.phplist.com/). I believe it does tracking.

Comment: Yes I cannot use Mailchimp for that reason. That is why I use my own server and thunderbird to send out my emails. I am just looking for a free service that will track the emails and that I can embed code to see the results.